# mysql sum and count per category append to matching category rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying to derive a MySQL query that turns this:

```
product | sold
milk    |  6
milk    |  4
bread   |  3
bread   |  2
bread   |  2
```

to this;

```
product | sold | total order   | Total sold
milk    |  2   |       2       |     6
milk    |  4   |       2       |     6
bread   |  3   |       3       |     7
bread   |  2   |       3       |     7
bread   |  2   |       3       |     7
```

I've been able to get the queries for sums and counts no problem, but I cannot seem to get it to join as a new column matching the product. Is this even possible? I've tried `WITH ROLLUP` but it just creates another row, not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join a simple query on this table with an aggregate query on:

```
SELECT a.product, a.sold, b.total_order, b.total_sold
FROM   mytable a
JOIN   (SELECT   product, COUNT(*) AS total_order, SUM(sold) AS total_sold
        FROM     mytable
        GROUP BY product) b ON a.product = b.product
```